# How can I find an object in a vector based on class properties?

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have a class `Attribute` with the property `std::string attributeName`. I would like to develop a simple function that returns the index of the `Attribute` that has an `attributeName` matching a provided string. Unfortunate restrictions include: I do not have c++0x at my disposal, and I  have already overloaded the `Attribute` == operator for something more complex. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

edit- I'm very sorry, I realized it is not clear that there is a vector of attributes I am searching in. `vector<Attribute> aVec`.

Comment: Would accessing the name via getter be out of the question?

Comment: Can there be more than one object with the same attribute value? Do you want a set of results, or the first match? Can the vector be reordered? Is performance important?

Answer (score 9):

Use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) with a custom [function object](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/functors-function-objects-in-c++.html):

```
class FindAttribute
{
    std::string name_;

public:
    FindAttribute(const std::string& name)
        : name_(name)
        {}

    bool operator()(const Attribute& attr)
        { return attr.attributeName == name_; }
};

// ...

std::vector<Attribute> attributes;
std::vector<Attribute>::iterator attr_iter =
    std::find_if(attributes.begin(), attributes.end(),
        FindAttribute("someAttrName"));
if (attr_iter != attributes.end())
{
    // Found the attribute named "someAttrName"
}
```

---

To do it in C++11, it actually not that different, except you obviously don't need a function object, or have to declare the iterator type:

```
std::vector<Attribute> attributes;

// ...

auto attr_iter = std::find_if(std::begin(attributes), std::end(attributes),
    [](const Attribute& attr) -> bool
    { return attr.attributeName == "someAttrName"; });
```

Or if you need to do this multiple times with different names, create the lambda function as a variable, and use [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) in the call to `std::find_if`:

```
auto attributeFinder =
    [](const Attribute& attr, const std::string& name) -> bool
    { return attr.attributeName == name; };

// ...

using namespace std::placeholders;  // For `_1` below

auto attr_iter = std::find_if(std::begin(attributes), std::end(attributes),
    std::bind(attributeFinder, _1, "someAttrName"));
```

Comment: Could you put the answer how to do it in modern C++, too, for the future?

Answer (score 2):

you can simply use a for loop for reaching this purpose:

```
for (int i = 0; i<aVec.size();i++)
{
    if(aVec[i].attributeName == "yourDesiredString")
    {
        //"i" is the index of your Vector.      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use bind function from boost library:

```
std::vector<Attribute>::iterator it = std::find_if(
     aVec.begin(),
     aVec.end(),
     boost::bind(&Attribute::attributeName, _1) == "someValue"
);
```

or C++11 bind function:

```
std::vector<Attribute>::iterator it = std::find_if(
    aVec.begin(),
    aVec.end(),
    std::bind(
        std::equal_to<std::string>(),
        std::bind(&Attribute::attributeName, _1),
        "someValue"
    )
);
```

without declaring the predicate class or function