# find a value in a vector of class objects

Tags: c++, class, object, vector, find

I have written a class-based vector:

```
class A {

private:

    string b;

    string c;

public:

    A(string n, string l) { b = l ;c = n; }

    struct Finder {

         Finder(std::string const& n) : name(n) { }  

         bool operator () ( const A & el) const  { return el.b == name; }

    private:

         std::string name;

    };

};


int main()

{

    vector<A> a1;

    a1.push_back(A("AA","aa"));

    a1.push_back(A("BB","bb"));

    a1.push_back(A("CC","cc"));

    a1.push_back(A("DD","dd"));


    vector<string>::iterator it;

    it = find_if(a1.begin(), a1.end(), A::Finder("CC"));

    if (it != a1.end()) {

        auto pos = it - a1.begin();

        cout << "CC is found at " << pos ;

    }
}
```

Now, I want to search for a value in a1. Let's say I want to find the index of element in which "CC" happens.

I found these similar solutions:

[Search a vector of objects by object attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517991/search-a-vector-of-objects-by-object-attribute)

[std::find Object by Member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445358/stdfind-object-by-member)

[How can I find an object in a vector based on class properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15063301/how-can-i-find-an-object-in-a-vector-based-on-class-properties)

[How to find an object with specific field values in a std::set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042578/how-to-find-an-object-with-specific-field-values-in-a-stdset)

As I implement all the comments in this section, I still get the errors! What did I miss? I guess the problem is in defining vector::iterator it;

error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

and,

error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: When posting error messages you should really indicate the line the compiler points to, otherwise we have to guess.

Comment: Would a `std::[multi]map<std::string, std::string>` not make more sense here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two solution as for my problem:

1. You can implement std::find in vector class-based object in c++:

   ```
   class A {
       private:
          string b;
          string c;
       public:
       A(string i) : b(i) {}
       A(string n, string l) { b = n ;c = l; }
       string Getb(){ return b; }
       string Getc(){ return c; }
       bool operator==(const A & obj2) const
       {
          return (this->b.compare(obj2.b) == 0); 
       }
   };


   int main()
   {
      vector<A> a1;
      a1.push_back(A("AA","aa"));
      a1.push_back(A("BB","bb"));
      a1.push_back(A("CC","cc"));
      a1.push_back(A("DD","dd"));

      auto it = find(a1.begin(), a1.end(), A("CC"));
      if (it != a1.end()) {
         auto idx = distance(a1.begin(), it);
         cout << "b= " << it->Getb() << " c= " << it->Getc() << endl;
         cout << "Index= " << idx << endl;
       } else
         cout << "CC is not found" << endl;
   return 0;
   }
   ```
2. You can implement std::find_if in vector class/structure based object in c++ (thanks to @Vlad from Moscow and @R Sahu):

   ```
   class A {
       private:
           string b;
           string c;
       public:
           A(string n, string l) { b = n ;c = l; }
           string Getb(){ return b; }
           string Getc(){ return c; }
           struct Finder {
               Finder(string const & n) : name(n) { }  
               bool operator () (const A & el) const { 
                    return el.Pos == name; 
                }
               string name;
           };
    };


   int main()
    {
        vector<A> a1;
        a1.push_back(A("AA","aa"));
        a1.push_back(A("BB","bb"));
        a1.push_back(A("CC","cc"));
        a1.push_back(A("DD","dd"));

        vector<A>::iterator it;
        it = find_if(a1.begin(), a1.end(), A::Finder ("CC"));
        if (it != a1.end()) {
            auto idx = distance(a1.begin(), it);
            cout << "b= " << it->Getb() << " c= " << it->Getc() << endl;
            cout << "Index= " << idx << endl;
        } else
            cout << "CC is not found" << endl;

     return 0;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

1. To use a `Predicate`, you'll need to use `std::find_if`, not `std::find`.

   ```
   it = std::find_if(a1.begin(), a1.end(), A::Finder("CC"));
   ```
2. Use `const&` in the argument type of `Finder::operator()`.

   Instead of

   ```
   bool operator () (A & el) { return el.b == name; }
   ```

   Use

   ```
   bool operator () (A const& el) { return el.b == name; }
   ```

   One of the requirements of `UnaryPredicate` is (from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate)

   > The function object pred shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator.

   Many compilers take it to mean that the argument type must be either a value or a `const&`.

Comment: Voted up. By not passing a reference, a copy is created each time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use standard algorithm `std::find_if`

```
it = find_if(a1.begin(), a1.end(), A::Finder("CC"));
```

Take into account that the inner clas should be defined like

```
struct Finder {

    Finder(std::string const& n) : name(n) { }  

    bool operator () ( const A & el) const  { return el.b == name; }

private:

    std::string name;

};
```

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, @R Sahu : I modify my code (as above), however I still get the same errors! Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow, @R Sahu : I finally found the solution to my problem. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @Afrand  It seems you have  a wrong order of data member initialization Instead of A( std::string n, std::string l ) { b = l ;c = n; } there should be A( std::string n, std::string l ) { b = n ;c = l; }  that is b should be initialized by n. And declare the parameters like const A &