# Compare templated type to certain class/type in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to find the type of thee class passed into a template as such

```
template<typename ret> 
ret copy(ret var){
    if(ret == int){ //problematic line
       cout << "int" << endl;
    }
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    auto b = copy(a);
    cout << b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But it is returning an error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘ret copy(ret)’:
main.cpp:15:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘==’ token
     if(ret == int){
            ^~
main.cpp:15:15: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
     if(ret == int){
               ^~~
main.cpp:15:15: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
```

How can I do this properly? Thanks

Comment: explicitly checking for type this way is usually a symptom of a bad design. Look into template specialization or in your case you could overload the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike python, in C++ `int` is not an object of type `class` (or something along those lines). You can't compare it like that. Instead, you can use

```
template<typename ret> 
ret copy(ret var)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<ret, int>)
    {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    // and so on....
```

**Edit:** (in response to comments by yaodav)

Note that `if constexpr` is supported only by C++17. There are alternatives such as:

```
    if (std::is_same<ret, int>::value)
    {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
```

but the disadvantage is that if one needs to do anything more complex to `var`, such as `var * 2`, then they'd get a syntax error for `ret` of type  `std::vector<int>`. The `if constexpr` syntax is not susceptible to this kind of errors, since it does not try to compile the code when `if constexpr` is false (it only does basic parsing it needs for finding the last `}`.

If one needs an older C++ version, then the only viable option is overloading:

```
void copy_helper(int var) {
    std::cout << "int\n";
}
template <class T>
void copy_helper(const T&) {}

template<typename ret> 
ret copy(ret var)
{
   copy_helper(var);
```

Also note (another comment by yaodav), that using such `if` construct is a sign of bad design. In general, I prefer to condition things based on properties and capabilities, rather than on specific types (and my overloading example from above is a condition too narrow). For example, if I need an integral type (with +,-,*,/, etc.), then  I prefer to condition the code based on the existence of these capabilities.

Comment: but notice that `if constexpr` is from c++17 and `std::is_same` from 11

Comment: @yaodav good point, but without `if constexpr` the meaning or the syntax diverges too much, and overloaing becomes the only reasonable option (if the OP intends to do anything smarter than just printing a predefined string)

Comment: if he is a student usually thy learn 98, then the `typeid` is his only option (or template specialization) as you can see in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845848/c-returning-reference-to-an-item-in-vector-from-class/60846431#60846431) he has 3 whys to do it depend on the standart that he working with

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comments, explicit type checking like this is generally a bad design. You can read about template meta-programming, specialization for a better solution to your problem.

If you can use run-time type information, here is a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename ret>
ret copy(ret var){
    if(typeid(var) == typeid(int)){
       std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    }
    return var;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    auto b = copy(a);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;

    double c = 2.0;
    auto d = copy(c);
    std::cout << d << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```